# A better way to implement a pattern repeating in several different places in the code

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following pattern repeating in several different places in my code:

```
if (m_condition)
{
    auto& item = m_vector[m_index];
    // Do something with 'item'
}
else
{
    for (auto& item : m_vector)
    {
        // Do something with 'item'
    }
}
```

Where `m_condition`, `m_vector` and `m_index` are class members.

The `Do something with 'item'` part is different in each occurrence of the pattern.

I am looking for a nicer/cleaner/shorter way to implement this (performance is not an issue).

I came up with this, but it feels kinda "nasty":

```
auto iBgnIndex = m_condition ? m_index : 0;
auto iEndIndex = m_condition ? m_index : m_vector.size()-1;
for (auto i = iBgnIndex; i <= iEndIndex; i++)
{
    // Do something with 'm_vector[i]'
}
```

What better options do I have?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just extract that into a function of its own?

Comment: @user2296177: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Put your first block of code inside a function with appropriate parameters then call it wherever you are using said pattern. Your `// Do something with 'item'` can be a parameter callable.

Comment: @user2296177: Great, well how do I do that (i.e., make the `Do something with 'item'` part a parameter callable)?

Comment: There isn't enough information to decide. Is the problem that you either want to do something to one element or all elements based on a boolean?

Comment: @rationalcoder: Yes, I want to do a bunch of operations - either on a single element (whose index is at my possession) in the vector, or on all elements in the vector. Why is there not enough information? Thanks.

Comment: It just isn't entirely clear that the somethings you want to do are the exact same thing until you finish reading the last snippet. Now that I am sure, I can give you a solution.

Comment: @rationalcoder: Great, thanks, where is it then?

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky because this type of recurring pattern is best solved in a slightly more specific context. Doing one this "one or all thing" is difficult to write readably in general.

That being said, here is a solution that will work in your case with indices(for convenience) and custom or standard iterators (I harcoded the index as an `int` for clarity here):

```
template <typename IndexedContainer_, typename UnaryOp_>
void apply_for_index(const IndexedContainer_& c, int index, UnaryOp_ op)
{
    if (index == -1)
        for (auto& elem : c) op(elem);
    else
        op(c[index]);
}

template <typename ForwardContainer_, typename Iterator_, typename UnaryOp_>
void apply_for_iter(const ForwardContainer_& c, Iterator_ it, UnaryOp_ op)
{
    if (it == c.end())
        for (auto& elem : c) op(elem);
    else
        op(*it);
}
```

Here is some example usage:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<int> elems = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    printf("All:\n");

    bool cond = false;
    int four_or_all = cond ? 4 : -1;
    apply_for_index(elems, four_or_all, [](int elem) {
        printf("elem=%d\n", elem);
    });

    printf("\nSpecifically 4:\n");

    four_or_all = !cond ? 4 : -1;
    apply_for_index(elems, four_or_all, [](int elem) {
        printf("elem=%d\n", elem);
    });

    printf("\nAll with iterators:\n");

    auto four_or_all_iter = cond ? elems.begin() + 4 : elems.end();
    apply_for_iter(elems, four_or_all_iter, [](int elem) {
        printf("elem=%d\n", elem);
    });

    printf("\nSpecifically 4 with iterators:\n");

    four_or_all_iter = !cond ? elems.begin() + 4 : elems.end();
    apply_for_iter(elems, four_or_all_iter, [](int elem) {
        printf("elem=%d\n", elem);
    });

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, when you solve the issue at this level, you end up using some kind of flag or sentinel values which can be hard to read.

Comment: @goodvibration please upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: I upvoted, but didn't accept because I am looking for something cleaner/shorter than what I already have.

Comment: @goodvibration It is technically shorter, but the point of my answer was to show you that aren't going to do much better than what you ended up with if you try to solve this issue at this level. Maybe if you could give some example context in which your solution might look like this, we could look for a cleaner solution at a higher level?